# Build for production Electron (using npm and webpack)

Tags: npm, webpack, electron

When I build my Electron app for production I still get a `node_modules` folder with the dependencies. The folder is constituted by:

1. The dependencies which are installed via package.json I already noticed that I can just delete them from the folder (since their code is inside webpack `bundle.js` )
2. ffprobe-static, which actually occupies the largest amount with 40Mb
3. The `node`js modules such as `ajv`,`deferential`, `debug`, `decamelize`, etc (158 folders total, while I don't even know most of them, let alone use them directly)

Regarding 2: Is it mandatory to have the binary for ffprobe-static? Can I use ffprobe-static with the `ffmpeg.dll` given alongside Electron binary?

Regarding 3: Why do I need these and how can I get rid of them? Also, Electron binary already comes with an 18.9Mb `node.dll` file. Again, can't I use this instead of having again the node_modules?

Comment: You run your build as `--prunue=true` ?? this will delete all the folders useless to your compiled project

Comment: Yes I did. I noticed that some modules can't be used in webpack (like `electron-window-manager`) and the node dependencies that I see are related to that...